# get TimeZone in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to get TimeZone of a client in gwt, and the only way that I have found is

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.createTimeZone(new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
```

but getTimezoneOffset() has been deprecated. I'm wondering if there is any non-deprecated way to get the TimeZone object.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method:

```
TimeZone.createTimeZone(String tzJSON)
```

Fromt GWT documentation:

> Applications can get such a string from the TimeZoneConstants class,
>   or it can request the string from the server. Either way, the
>   application obtains the original string from the data provided in the
>   TimeZoneConstant.properties file, which was carefully prepared from
>   CLDR and Olson time zone database.

You typically do not want all of these Strings on your client. I use an RPC call to retrieve only the string that I need.

Note that this is a more accurate method for creating a time zone, because time zone offset may be different on different dates.